# Echo commented lines into a properties txt file

Tags: linux, echo

Is there any way we can redirect commented data into txt files using echo command?

For eg:

```
echo #abcd1  
      abcd2
      abcd3 >> newFile.txt
```

I need to comment out the entire block that I am redirecting into the text file. Hence, after executing echo, the newFile.txt should look like:

```
#abcd1
#abcd2
#abcd3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it.

```
$ echo \#foo > foo
$ cat foo
#foo
```